# How is Diffie-Hellman secure when the exchanged number is a power of the generator less than the modulo

Tags: diffie-hellman

I'm trying to understand how Diffie-Hellman is still secure when $A$ ends up being a power of $g$ less than $p$.

I chose $p$, where p is prime, and $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

$g=2$ and $p=29$

Now considering Alice creating her $A$ where  $A=2^a\mod{29}$. If she chooses $a=30$ this results in $2^{30}=4\mod{29}$, which means I can trivially recover an $a$ with the same result $a=log_2{4}=2$ and use that to recover the shared secret.

In general any returned $A$ that is a power of $2$ less than $29$ (ie. $2,4, 8,16$) can be trivially recovered by taking $log_2{A}$ and getting a valid $a$.

How does Diffie-Hellman resist against this? Am I missing something else? I know I chose a small $a$ and $p$ but it seems this problem would exist with large $a$ and $p$ too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $g^a<p$, then the discrete logarithm mod $p$ becomes plain logarithm, even for a 2048-bit $p$. So, you are right that in this case $a$ can be easily computed from $g^a$. However, this is not bad because there are only at most $\log_2 p$ such $a$s (that satisfy $g^a<p$). Compared to $p$, $\log_2 p$ is a negligible number. In other words, since $a$ is chosen uniformly at random from $p-1$ values, the probability that it falls into the first $\log_2 p$ values is negligible (in $\log_2 p$, the bit length of $p$).

Comment: Addition: It's been [experimentally and publicly demonstrated](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/697) that we can solve the DLP modulo $p$ for $\log_2 p\approx795$. In the question, $\log_2 p\approx5$. @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the choice of $a$ must satisfy $1 \leq a < p$, The exponent $a = 30$, for this prime, is equivalent to the exponent $2$ because $30 \equiv 2 \mod{\phi(29)}$.

Secondly, as you stated the $p$ is very small. Thus, with a paper and pencil one can calculate the discrete log problem. When you consider, the recommended size of $p$ as 2048-bit (see at [update of RFC4419](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-curdle-ssh-dh-group-exchange-02.html)) you will face the real problem.

When $a$ is chosen randomly, it will have 2047-bits with 1/2 probability-think of the MSB has 1/2 probability to equal 1. Now consider calculating discrete logarithm problem. The complexity is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{p})$ with [Baby-step giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step). With [Pollard's kangaroo algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_kangaroo_algorithm) it is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{b-a})$ where the algorithm selects a set $\{a,\ldots, b\}$, the [original paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-143/S0025-5718-1978-0491431-9/S0025-5718-1978-0491431-9.pdf).